# laravel raw queries last_insert_id

Tags: php, laravel, last-insert-id

Is there a way to get the `last_insert_id` when using laravel's raw query?

`DB::query('INSERT into table VALUES ('stuff') ')`

This returns true or false. Is there a way to get last_insert_id using raw queries in Laravel?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just the benefit of those who might have be having the same question for laravel 4, there is a slight syntax change from @haso-keric's response.

It is:

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(array('email' => 'example@gmail.com')
```

Comment: at time of writing, this also works in lumen :) (so I presume Laravel 5.4 too)

Comment: I wonder why was this accepted with all the upvotes, when question explicitly asked for raw queries. Though I agree that one really *shouldn't* use raw queries for this.

Answer (score 7):

Try `DB::Query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()')`?

(this is DB product specific, example I've given is for MySQL/MariaDB.)

Answer (score 3):

For Laravel 4:

`$id = DB::select('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');`

Explanation:

`when using the lovely Laravel 4 PHP framework for websites etc, you should refer to the "DB::Select" function instead of "DB::Query" for raw queries. As "DB::Query" throws an error. I believe this is because its deprecated from v3, or plain doesn't exist. Yours, Smith.`

Comment: when using the lovely Laravel 4 PHP framework for websites etc, you should refer to the "DB::Select" function instead of "DB::Query" for raw queries. As "DB::Query" throws an error. Yours, Smith.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting a record that has an auto-incrementing ID? You can use the insert_get_id method to insert a record and retrieve the ID:

$id = DB::table('users')->insert_get_id(array('email' => 'example@gmail.com'));
Note: The insert_get_id method expects the name of the auto-incrementing column to be "id".

Answer (score 0):

Just use underlying PDO instance:

```
DB::connection()->getPdo()->lastInsertId();
```